# Convert vhd to vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant

I have a number of windows VMs running on my hyper-v instance I want to turn into vagrant boxes. Its there a tool out there that can do this for me or a clear guide on what needs to be enabled on the machine and how to create the config files that go into the box?

The documentation for windows VMs coming from hyper-v seem to be lacking with most guides focusing on virtual box.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct approach to achieve what you want.

> NOTE: remove the hyper-v integration tools (agent, PV drivers etc...).

- First, you need to convert VHD to VMDK or **VDI** format using `VBoxManage`, for example from VHD to VDI -> `VBoxManage clonehd source.vhd target.vdi --format VDI`
- Once done, create a VM in VirtualBox with a proper spec (# of vCPUs, Memory, etc.), use the existing converted `.vdi` file as its virtual disk.
- Try to boot the VM and see if everything works as expected. Install the VirtualBox Guest Additions (recommended).
- Configure the VM as per Vagrant Documentation (e.g. NAT port forwarding rules, disabling UAC etc., refer to [Creating a Base Box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html))
- Package it as Vagrant box `vagrant package --base vbox_vm_name --output /file/to/name.box`